# Negative Kullback-Leiber divergence? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

The Kullback-Leiber divergence is defined the following way:

If $A$ and $B$ are continuous probability distributions on $X$, then

$$KL(A,B) = \int_{X} A(x) \log \left(\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}\right)dx$$

We've learned that this value is always non-negative.

However let's take $X = [0,1]$ and $B(x) \equiv 1$, which is a valid continuous p.d.f. Then

$$KL(A,B) = \int_0^1 A(x) \log \left(\frac{A(x)}{1}\right)dx = \int_0^1 A(x) \log \left(A(x)\right)dx = -H(A) \le 0$$

Where $H(A)$ denotes the entropy of distribution $A$, which we've also learned is non-negative. It's defined for continuous variables the following way:

$$H(A) = -\int_{X} A(x) \log \left(A(x)\right)dx \ge 0$$

(And therefore, $-H(A)$ is the value shown above.)

Since $A$ can be anything, we can choose one such that $H(A) > 0$, so $-H(A) < 0$.

But this contradicts with what I have learned. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Differential entropy can be negative. Consider a uniform real random variable on the interval $[0,0.1]$

Comment: @Joe indeed, it seems that he has proven that it is always $\le 0$ if the random value is limited to an interval of size 1. I don't know how to demonstrate it directly with the expression of $H(A)$.

Comment: @ArnaudMégret, I'm not sure if this would be "direct", but Gibb's inequality gives $-\int p(x) \log[ p(x) ] dx \le -\int p(x) \log[ q(x) ] dx$ for any PDFs $p$ and $q$, and letting $q$ be the PDF of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ we have that $\log[q(x)]=0$.  Of course, Gibb's inequality is equivalent to the non-negativity of the KL divergence.